# PHP. Заменить в массиве отрицательные элементы в положительные

Tags: php

Дан массив М (20). Создать программу, которая преобразует отрицательные элементы этого массива в положительные.

Comment: `array_map('abs', $m)`

Answer (score 4):

эволюция кода при изучении пхп
дано

```
$m = [1,-1,...];
```

итерация первая

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($m); $i++){
    if($m[$i] < 0){
        $m[i] = -$m[$i];
    } 
}
```

итерация вторая

```
$len = count($m);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
   ....
}
```

итерация 2.1

```
 $n = count($m);
 while($n--){ 
    $m[$n] = ....
 }
```

итерация третья

```
foreach($m as $idx => $v){
   if($v < 0) $m[$idx] = -$v;
}
```

четвертая

```
foreach($m as &$v){
   if($v < 0 )   $v = -$v;
}
```

пять.один

```
foreach($m as &$v){
    $v = $v < 0 ? -$v : $v;
}
```

пять.два

```
 foreach($m as &$v){
     $v = $v * ($v < 0 ? -1 : 1);
 }
```

шесть

```
 foreach($m as &$v) $v = abs($v);
```

семь

```
array_walk($m, function(&$v){
        $v = abs($v);
    });
```

восемь

```
$m = array_map(function($v){ return abs($v); }, $m);
```

восемь.один

```
$m = array_map($fn($v) => abs($v), $m);
```

девять

```
$m = array_map('abs', $m);
```

Comment: зы: на самом деле вариант с `for/while` и возможно `walk` будет наиболее эффективным.